# CMS with Editable Region Classes

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, content-management-system

I have seen many Content Management Systems that allow users to define what is editable by defining "editable" in the  class.  I was basically wondering how this works with a CMS using PHP and MYSQL.  I was thinking maybe Jquery scans the DOM for the specified class and places some code inside that div.  Can someone point me in the right direction as I am wanting to upgrade my CMS to work with this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already get it pretty much as it works. Hint some elements that can be edited inside the DOM, extend hinted elements with javascript to add the editing capabilities. Changes need to be fired with AJAX to the PHP backend which stores the changes into the DB. Next time the page is fully requested from server, those regions contain the data stored in the DB.

Comment: I think the only part that is confusing me (and is probably really simple) is how the database would store the information.  I can understand having a simple template with a sidebar and main content being saved to the database in a simple CMS, but since the user can define so many elements as editable, would some code count how many editable elements are on the page and create new rows in the database.  PHP would just have to remember somehow.

Comment: Yes, each element should have an id (must not be the DOM id, but could be), so that when you fire the ajax save request, the backend script knows which element was edited. The PHP code must also check if the current user is allowed to edit (that) element.

Comment: Ok, so I understand how to edit and send edits back to the database using AJAX and checking if the user has permissions, I guess the only thing I am wondering how to do (if you can maybe point me in some sample code) is how to use AJAX to find elements (or divs) with a specified class, count them, and add them to a database table.  The problem is, how does AJAX know where the DIV is?  Would AJAX have to add a snippet of code inside the DIV dynamically and give that element a more specified "id" such as "id_1" or something.

Comment: @drummer392: Do you know jQuery? I is heavliy making use of CSS selectors to find element. So in CSS `div.editable` will return all <div>'s that are editable. If yoh then use the `id` attribute for the id, maybe with a prefix, so it starts as a word rather then a number, you have all the information you need.

Comment: Thanks.  I know a little bit of Jquery.  Still learning, but I've used it alot in my projects.  Is there a way to rename a specific class and give it a unique ID using PHP and/or Jquery?  I think that will be perfect for what I need to do.

Comment: The ID ypu to assign on the PHP side because it's related to the unique ID you have got in your data (compare to *primary key* in a RDBMS like MySQL). You can output class names and id's inside the HTML source you return from you PHP script. This is the interface you have with the browser which will execute the javascript you provide as well. You have a contract with the browser how things work together. So if your provide elements of class editable and ids which refer to the data in question, the browser must only extend on editable elements and submit the changed data identified by a tag id.

Comment: I understand how to do the id's and classes on the divs, but is there a way that I can scan the page for "editable" class and change that class/id name to a unique name?  Then I imagine I could just use the .prepend functionality to insert my content into that specified div.

Comment: do this with jQuery for an easy way: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ - javascript has a context per each callback function, often `this`, referring to the element making it easy for you to read the id: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Thanks, those links provided insight on what I needed exactly.  I think my last question is: Once I set the ID's to something unique, how do I keep those unique values so if the page layout changed, the information won't get lost or messed up.  Again, I'm having Jquery scan the document so for a certain class with a selector, then I am renaming the ID to something unique using .removeclass and .addclass in Jquery.  It is very confusing because I could just have a code copy the document and replace the code and save it, but if the user changes their code then the IDs will get messed up.

Comment: What I ended up doing was utilizing the .append and .prepend functions in Jquery.  Exactly what I need!